# Pandas: merging Series values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe as below. How can I merge the `round` and `square` values under `shape` Series as `other`? (In R terminology, I want to merge the `round` and `square` levels of the `shape` factor into a new level labelled `other`.)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,9),
                    'code' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                                'two', 'three', 'one', 'two'],
                    'shape': ['round', 'triangular', 'triangular','triangular','square',
                                        'triangular','round','triangular'],
                    'amount' : np.random.randn(8)},  columns= ['id','code', 'shape', 'amount'])
df 
   id   code       shape    amount
0   1    one       round -0.187789
1   2    one  triangular  1.286208
2   3    two  triangular  0.171734
3   4  three  triangular  0.394471
4   5    two      square -0.009613
5   6  three  triangular  0.413767
6   7    one       round  1.264730
7   8    two  triangular  0.516499
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you mean?

```
df.loc[df['shape'].isin(['round', 'square']), 'shape'] = 'other'
```

(edited after @TomAugspurger's suggestion)

Comment: yes, I believe so. Pandas Series have no levels so I need not worry about dropping levels (`round` and `square`), right?

Comment: they are strings, so I don't think you should worry

Comment: You may want to change that to `df.loc[df['shape'].isin(['round', 'square']), 'shape'] = 'other'` to avoid a possible setting on copy error. Doesn't seem to be a problem here, but it's best to avoid chained assignment.

Comment: @TomAugspurger, could you give a reference on "a possible setting on copy error". I dont understand how accessing by index works in Pandas. When does it create a copy and when does it modify the object directly? In this case I want the `data` to be modified directly.

Comment: Here's the section in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). It's a messy topic. Like I said, the original answer seemed to be fine in this case, but it's good to get in the habit.